# Change document root. Migrating from MAMP to AMPPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost, server, document-root

I hope this does not seem like a stupid question: I have been using MAMP for several years, and what I love about it (as opposed to WAMP) is that I can open the app point the Web Server at any folder on my system and localhost will run as the root on that folder.

With AMPPS it seems everything is stored in www. So if I have lots of projects (which I do) I want to be able to write links to my assets as root based urls (for example):

```
 /css/main.css
```

At the moment this will assume that www is the root, whereas I want

www/project1

www/project2

What is the best approach to handle this? And is there a way to make it more automated than having to change config every time I want to run the server.

**CAVEAT** (I am not particularly familiar with points 1 and 2):

1. Can write a .htaccess file with rewrite rules (but will I need to change this per project, or can a single .htaccess file handle all of my projects, with multiple rules).
2. Can I add multiple projects to httpd.conf? And does this require updates to the hosts file?

I can set base url tag in each project (although that seems really antiquated, and is not very portable when deploying files to another location).

What I really want to do is replicate the MAMP functionality of being able to point at any folder and run that as the root.

Apologies if this is a bit woolly.

Comment: Bit of an update, it does seem that AMPPS is writing to the hosts file automatically, as well as updating httpd-vhosts.conf so the projects are being mapped, I just want to know how to set /project1 as the root. Or switch between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have most of this working.

The issue to create an entry in the hosts file which is mapped to a name.

So I can create a new domain in 'Add New Domain'

I enter a url:

```
 /Applications/AMPPS/www/tmp
```

And also add a domain name

```
 local.tmp
```

Then run http://local.tmp in the browser. Now links to images, css and js will work if I set them as root links. Like:

```
 /css/main.css
 /js/site.js
```

The only issue is that I am using php includes for header and footer etc, and these have to be written relatively it seems.

So:

```
 /common/header.php
```

Won't work from inside a file, but that is OK I simply set that as relative (that is probably good practice anyway.

Thanks to @Jigar for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In enduser panel i.e `http://localhost/ampps` you can create domains(i.e VirtualHost). It provides an option to add an entry in `hosts` file.

> Can write a .htaccess file with rewrite rules (but will I need to
>   change this per project, or can a single .htaccess file handle all of
>   my projects, with multiple rules).

You can create in .htaccess for each project. Place the .htaccess in the document root of the VirtualHost created.

> Can I add multiple projects to httpd.conf? And does this require updates to the hosts file?

If you want to manually add configuration, you can do that but avoid doing anything in `httpd.conf`, instead create a new conf file and include it in httpd.conf like other vhosts configuration like Ampps does. Have a look at below section of the file httpd.conf where line starts with `Include ....`

Comment: Yes but how do I run each project as the root? I want project1 to be localhost, rather than localhost/project1 which it is at the moment.

Comment: OK, well I have it half working now, I am going to post my own answer, but yours has definitely helped me. Only me asking 'can I do this' is not the same as 'do I need to do this'. Thank you.